# Changing font in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fonts, kpfonts, amssymb

I am very, very new to LaTeX, and I've been trying to understand fonts but as far as I can tell, it is too complicated for me at this point.

All I really want to do, is change the `amssymb` version of `\mathbb{R, N, C, etc.}` for the `kpfonts` one. Can anyone help? Please keep in mind, that I'm a dumbo :)

Comment: NB: It is quite good that this is difficult. Using the same font gives the document a consistent and complete overall look and feel, which is very desirable. Arbitrary switching of fonts is word processor heathenry. Keep in mind that the precise appearance of a given glyph is irrelevant to its meaning, much as it doesn't matter if my 'a' has the hook on the top, or if my 'g' has a loop in the descender. of course, you may feel that one glyph looks better than another, but you should consider seriously whether this aesthetic improvement outweighs the inconsistent appearance.

Comment: You wouldn't use a specific font just for the 'a's now, would you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to change only `\mathbb{}`, you can load `amssymb` or whatever *first* and then override the declaration of `\mathbb{}`, using relevant code from `kpfonts.sty`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
% from kpfonts.sty
\DeclareSymbolFont{kpbb}{U}{jkpsyb}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{kpbb}{bold}{U}{jkpsyb}{bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{kpbb}

\begin{document}
  $\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

[image: KP bb]

This does consume an additional maths font but, unless you really can't afford that, this is a relatively straightforward approach.